# Detect if the app has been refunded via Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I was just wondering if there is a way for us to detect/get notified when (/if) a refund occurs for the app in question (on the actual app, not any IAP). Will an event of some sort be broadcasted? If so, would it be a broadcast as a refund or a "general uninstall" (`android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED`)?

I haven't quite found anything while searching the web, but I reckon someone else must've thought of this before me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additionally.. anybody can export apk before refunding. What are good ways to stop that?